# How best to format and position legend in line chart when legend text is long?

Tags: graphics, formatting

I always struggle when showing line chart with long legend title like this:

[image]

Is there any best practice to a chart with long legend title?

I try to show several alternatives below, but of course, it's not comprehensive.

(a) Stretch y-axis limit

[image]

(b) Put legend outside chart's body

[image]

(c) Shorten legend title

[image]

#### Update

I'm a researcher in computer science field. But, general discussions beyond research domains are also welcome.

Comment: Note that specific journals may have their own styling preferences for the legend.

Comment: @Bitwise Thanks. I'm interested especially in CS field. Unfortunately, I have no idea about style preference about this topic even in my field, and would appreciate if you could give some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

When it's not *too* big, I recommend shrinking the legend font size and whitespace and reducing the complexity of the labels.  If it's very big, however, I recommend instead moving to a systematic coloring scheme and explaining the coloring scheme in the caption rather than a legend.